# Difference between Grid Computing and SOA?

Tags: soa, grid-computing, globus-toolkit

I'm a student and I have a semester paper called 'GRID COMPUTING' and another called 'SOA'.

I've created SOA-based web services as part of my lab exercise. But it seems Grid Computing deals with the same WSDL-based services. I can't actually spot the difference between Grid Computing and SOA. (Now I have to do a project in Globus Toolkit.)

My question is:

**What is the difference between Grid Computing and SOA?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Grid Computing* is the **infrastructure to run** applications.
*SOA* is a **way to build** applications.

They are not related. In a nutshell,

1. It is possible to expose the power of grid computing as web services (which is what Globus has done)
2. It is possible to develop SOA solutions via web services (which most companies end up doing)

Comment: Thank you . Another question... My intention is to develop webservices in java using Globus . Globus site says that only JavaWs Core can be installed in Windows . Is that enough for me ? ( I'm not going to develop anything advanced ... )

Answer (score 1):

Grid Computing is similar to a cluster that can take many different types of workload.    SOA is a philosophy.  SOA is about reuse.   The anti-SOA is building applications in silos.